# Get bundle from webpack-dev-middleware

Tags: webpack, sails.js, webpack-2, webpack-dev-middleware

I have configured webpack-dev-middleware with **sails**. The `publicPath` in webpack configuration is set to `/static/`. Webpack builds the `bundle.js` without errors, but it is not available at `localhost:3000/static/bundle.js`.

How do I inject the bundle? Is there anything specific I need to do for sails?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `publicPath` in two locations: the Webpack configuration, but also the `webpack-dev-middleware` options.

For instance, this is what I use (on Express, so not entirely sure if it'll work exactly the same with Sails):

```
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackConfig        = require('./webpack.dev');
const compiler             = require('webpack')(webpackConfig);

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  noInfo     : true,
  publicPath : webpackConfig.output.publicPath
}));
```

(I have a separate Webpack configuration file called `webpack.dev.js`)

As you can see, I just re-use the `publicPath` from the Webpack configuration for the middleware.

Comment: I have the exact same setting. It doesn't seem to work for sails.

Comment: If Sails handles requests to `/static` itself, it may be interfering with the Webpack middleware. You could try to use a different `publicPath` for Webpack to see if that makes any difference.